# Only on Mac OS X strange SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: node.js, express

This is a error:

```
~/reporting.js:689
    .get(async function salesReport(req, res, next) {
         ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

This is a method:

```
router.route('/reporting/reports/sales-report')
.get(async function salesReport(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.query.date_from || !req.query.date_to) return next({message: "Date range not defined"})
    try {
        let r = await getSalesReportData(req.query.date_from, req.query.date_to, req.query.sort, req.query.limit, req.query.page)
        res.json(r);
    } catch(e) {next(e)}
})
```

And on Ubuntu 16.04 server work perfect and not trow errors.
NodeJS -v: v7.5.0
npm -v: 5.3.0

Comment: You can use `await/async` without flags only in node version starting from v7.6.0

Comment: [https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/02/node-76-async-await](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/02/node-76-async-await)

Comment: @alexmac thanks! This is the solution